# How Magento2 Checks If To Serve Request From Cache Or From DataSource?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, caching

Example: We have a Full Page Cached Category Page, How System Know Weather To Send Cached Data as a Response, Or Hit Database and Send response.
If it uses any cache tag, where does it check?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of the block classes extend to the class

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
```

which also extends to the abstract class

```
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
```

and with fpp activated the block html is always loaded from cache.
In the abstrtact class, have a look on the toHtml() and _loadCache() functions, where the check and the load is happening. If you add in your block class the following function then the block html is not loaded from cache.

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return null;
}
```